# Looking for a noun meaning something you are given to work with

Tags: word-choice

As part of a task in a psychological experiment I have a "transformation table" that contains two rows of letters:

```
A    B    C    D    ...
Z    R    K    Q    ...
```

The participants are given a selection of letters (e.g. "B") and must transform them with the help of this table (e.g. "B" into "R").

To explain this procedure there is an example that gives a sample letter and a sample transformation, e.g.:

```
...    result
B      R
```

The text above the two letters should explain that the "B" is the letter that is given to the participants as "source material" or "input", and that the "R" is the result after the transformation.

**What is the noun that describes the stimulus given in an experiment?**

The verb used in this situation is "given", but there appears to be no noun with the corresponding meaning, since the noun "given" means something quite different, namely "a basic condition or assumption" (Merriam-Webster). And it is not a "prompt", because a prompt is not material to be processed.

---

The original German word I am translating this from is "Vorgabe". In this context it means "something that is given".

Comment: you mean given 'pattern', 'set', 'selection' or 'sequence'?

Comment: Are they actually _letters_? Can't you call them that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "stimulus" here, but I suspect it's probably not the right word for the context. As regards the word you're actually asking for, it seems to me you want the word which would normally be used as the "column heading" above **B** in your example. That word is simply **Input**.

Comment: @terdon Since both the "input" and the result are letters, calling both or one of them "letters" will be confusing. Also, there are more letters on the page (the transformed letters must be searched for in a sequence of letters).

Comment: @user49727 It's not a pattern or sequence, but single letters with no order to them. The whole task is: You are given two or more letters, you must transform them, then search for them in a long string of letters, and write down the letters to the left of them. It is a test to measure attention in ADHD patients (and treatment success) and rather tedious ;-)

Comment: @FumbleFingers The whole procedure is more like giving you something, from my hand to your hand. I don't feel "input" fits this action of the experimenter giving the participant a set of letters.

Comment: Why not *stimulus*?

Comment: @ what: Well, let's suppose this experiment involves "incentive payments" to the participants for each transformation they perform. I can't see anything unusual in an impatient participant (seeking to maximise his income, perhaps) saying *"I'm ready for the next **input**"*. But it would be *really* weird if he said *"Give me another **stimulus**, please."*

Comment: Another example where the word I'm looking for might be used is the dots with numbers in "drawing by numbers": you are given the dots and have to use them to create the drawing. They are not a stimulus, but the starting point / raw material for your activity.

Comment: Hmm, you're right there, @FumbleFingers.

Comment: Using mathematical terminology, for a function f (the rule for the transformation - which may simply be no more than a given set of ordered pairs), if f(x) = y, x is often called the **argument**. This is probably too technical a term - why not stick with 'input' and 'output' (which terms cover the sum total of all members of each set, as well as each member individually).

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking the participants to do is "decode" or "[decipher](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/decipher)" the text.  As such, the "input" could be considered a code or a [cipher.](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/cipher)

> **Cipher** - noun - secret or disguised way of writing; a code:
>
> Usage: he was writing cryptic notes in a cipher
>
> Usage: the information may be given in cipher
>
> Alternate Definition: a thing written in a cipher.
>
> Alternate Definition: a key to such a cipher.

or

> [Code](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/cipher) - noun - system of words, letters, figures, or other symbols substituted for other words, letters, etc., especially for the purposes of secrecy:
>
> Usage: the Americans cracked their diplomatic code
>
> Usage: sending messages in code

Answer (score 0):

While *stimulus/response* is a standard pairing in psychology experiments, I understand that you wish to avoid these.

Consider

- [**cue**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/cue)

> a signal for action

- [**signal**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/signal)

> anything that acts as an incitement to action

- [**starting point**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/starting-point)

> a starting point for a discussion or process can be used to begin it or act as a basis for it

Comment: Hmm, actually I like "cue". Isn't that what an actor is given when he forgets his text? That's pretty close to what goes on here.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest ***source*** which is less cybernetic and implies the start of a process.

Answer (score 0):

The mathematical/dynamical-systems terms are

Initial Conditions:
Conditions with which a process is started.

Results or Resultant Conditions:
The results at the terminal-end point of the process.

Initial Variables/Parameters/Arguments:
The variables/parameters/arguments that are part of the initial conditions.

Initial Vectors:
The term *vector* is used when there is indirection to the conditions. For example *disease vectors*, *vector of comprehension rates or directions*. *Vectors* is suitably used when you have a matrix of initial values.

Given:
The term "given" is often used as descriptive participle for initial conditions.

Thus,

> Given an initial set of conditions ...
>   The given initial vectors/values/conditions/arguments/parameters are blah, blah, blah ...